# ASPxComboBox SelectedIndexChange event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress, aspxcombobox

I have two Comboboxes in an DNN Module and if I change the first one, the second one should change dynamically to a certain index.

I already tried it with javascript and in the code- behind file but with no success.

Maybe someone can explain how it works or give me a short code example?
Thanks!

Comment: could you provide some that is not working.. No one will do you work for you..Show your efforts and then ask for the problem where did you stuck.. DevExpress has nice documentation for client scripts [ASPxClientComboBox Class](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientComboBoxtopic) -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example how it works and how to do it on devexpress controlls

http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/ASPxComboBox/ClientAPI.aspx